# Looking to add more .dat auto responses to Fiddler i.e. 500, 504, etc

Tags: fiddler

I am trying to add more basic server response code error messages to to Fiddler auto responder. In the dropdown there are currently a bunch of .dat files with responses such as 404, 502, etc. I would like to add more of these http codes but kind find how to do it. Is there a way to get more of these options in the auto responder?

Comment: I would recommend to use Fiddler script for that. It allows you to recognize as much different requests you want and send back a matching response. https://www.telerik.com/blogs/understanding-fiddlerscript

Answer (score 0):

You can add these in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Fiddler\ResponseTemplates`. The format could be copied from the existing ones, basically:

```
HTTP/1.1 <CODE> <MESSAGE>
<HEADER1>: <VALUE1>
<HEADER2>: <VALUE2>
...
```

Then restart Fiddler and the new response will be added in the UI.